# Users need Silverlight 4.0 for Expression Blend?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, expression-blend-4

I have Visual Studio 2010 beta 2 installed and Expression Blend Preview for .NET 4. When I began to debug it, it asked me to install Silverlight 4.0 beta. So now I am wondering if people who are going to view my application need to install Silverlight 4.0 instead of Silverlight 3.5. If so, how can I downgrade from 4.0 to 3.5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are creating apps in Expression Blend Preview for .NET 4 then you are going to get Silverlight 4.0 projects. You can however use Blend 3 to create Silverlight 3 projects. Visual Studio 2010 will also release to Silverlight 3 projects.

Comment: The only problem is that my trial version of Blend 3 ran out.

Comment: You could always re-install it to renew the trial.

Comment: Microsoft Expression Blend 4 Beta supports deploying Silverlight 3 projects as well as Silverlight 4, so I would snag that up.
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=6f014e07-0053-4aca-84a7-cd82f9aa989f